# Is defining a delimiter in a hive ORC Table useless?

Tags: hive, delimiter, orc

When you create a ORC table in hive, you are changing the file type to be orc. This means you can't look at a specific file outside of the orc table.

Here's an example orc create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_orc_v1
(
col1 int,
col2 int
)
PARTITIONED BY (odate date)
CLUSTERED BY (col1) INTO 10 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');
```

If I try to make this a csv table (like you do on a non-orc table) will it

1) not affect table performance
2) slow down performance as it converts things to a csv file that you can never read
3) give me some benefit that I'm not aware of
4) do something else

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using any binary format (ORC, AVRO, Parquet) to store you data then `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY` is just ignored, you can use it in your table syntax, it might not give you any error. However they are not being used